# What are all the advantages of BDD?

Tags: automation, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

What are all the advantages of BDD(Behaviour Driven development) framework and cucumber?

I want to know what are all the advantages of BDD.

Answer (score 5):

I totally agree the communication is one of the biggest advantage however the benefits are for all the parties involved and the advantages for those are different.

So briefly:

For All:

- living documentation
- collaboration, early discovery of unknowns
- enforce building domain vocabulary and semi formal language (DSL) to
  express system behaviour consistently within the organization

For devs:

- like TDD, it helps to think in chunks, create nice and testable code.
- write code for what is needed only (build the right thing)
- better coordination between different dev teams developing similar
  features with different technologies

For QA:

- ready acceptance criteria
- ready building blocks for all kind of tests
- test what is exactly need (test the right thing)

For PO:

- think and reason features in detail thus produce better specs
- better visual and coordination with other Managers and Product owners
- better visual and understanding on Devs and QAs output/report due to the same source/format of
  specs

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion, the biggest advantage of BDD is the increase of communication when you introduce it in the way it was meant.

An excellent article about this is from Richard Bradshaw - have a look at 
[Using BDD Tools To Write Automated Checks != BDD](http://www.thefriendlytester.co.uk/2015/08/using-bdd-tools-to-write-automated.html)

The idea is that the three amigos (QA, Dev, and Business) collaborate to create the feature files.  That leads as mentioned to a lot of communication before a story goes into production.

Another advantage (but surely not the main one) is that the test cases are human readable - and if you have to create reports for non-technical folks, you have it a bit easier.

But on the way of implementation, which I've often see, where the Testers have to create the features and implement the Tests by themselves is a huge overhead and is also an antipattern in BDD.

I hope that helped a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with [Thywen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484493/thywen), these are things BDD brings you:

- Better communication

  - Examples are easy to understand, discuss and criticize
  - Easier to find things you didn't know you didn't know.
  - Building the right thing
- Automated acceptance tests

  - The examples are executable